# Get a list of AWS pipelines ready for stage approval

Tags: bash, jq, aws-cli, aws-codepipeline

I have 40+ pipelines that I need to approve from dev to QA and then QA to stage.  I am working on a script to use AWS CLI commands to do do.  I have been able to do that for a single pipeline where I know that the specific pipeline is ready to be approved.

```
aws codepipeline put-approval-result --cli-input-json file://TestPipeline.json
```

This is how I gathered the information for the approval for a single pipeline

```
aws codepipeline get-pipeline-state --name Pipeline-Ready-for-Approval
```

What I am trying to find out is - is there a way to loop through all of the pipelines using the `get-pipeline-state` and identify the stage name and action name without manually going through output of each of the pipelines.

I can try to get the pipeline names from `aws codepipeline list-pipelines` to get the list to loop through.

Is it possible using bash script and awscli and jq together?

Thank you

Comment: Where is the JSON you have? What is the output you want to get from it? Where do you want to put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get most of the way there using the following

```sh
pipelines=$(aws codepipeline list-pipelines --query 'pipelines[].name' --output text)

for p in pipelines; do
    aws codepipeline get-pipeline-state \
        --name $p \
        --query 'stageStates[?latestExecution.status==`InProgress`].{stageName:stageName,actionName:actionStates[0].actionName,token:actionStates[0].latestExecution.token}'
done
```

This assumes the approval action exists as the *first* or *only* action within a stage.

You'll get the output required for the [`put-approval-result`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/put-approval-result.html) command

Comment: Thanks @maafk - I will work with the above commands.  I was looking at the query option to select only a those pipelines that satisfy only a certain pattern.  From some online examples, I tried `'pipelines[contains["pattern]].name'`  but that did not help.  Can you let me know, how should I formulate that query

Comment: I was able to filter for a pattern using `--query 'pipelines[?contains(name, `pattern`) == `true`].name'`