# Retrieve commit Id from AWS Codepipeline using CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, pipeline, aws-cli, aws-codepipeline

With help of @maafk I was able to get information about each pipeline in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122382/get-a-list-of-aws-pipelines-ready-for-stage-approval) question.  I am now trying to find the commit id for the prod step for each pipeline.  I have 40+ pipelines that I need to get commitids for and currently, i am doing it from console, by going to each pipeline, click on the details and copy the commitId from the pop-up.

I would like to automate this part and create an output file, that will have the pipeline name and the commit id for each of my 40+ pipelines.

I am trying to look for it in the json returned by `get-pipeline-state` but not finding it.  In some of the examples, I have seen there is a variable defined, where do I find that, if that is the correct way to get commit id?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using third party actions in your pipeline ? If so, have you looked at `get-third-party-job-details` ? It includes inputArtifacts where each artifact contains a `revision` (e.g. Github Commit Id)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the most recent commit id when usig Github as my source provider.

```sh
aws codepipeline get-pipeline-state \
    --name my-pipeline-name \
    --query 'stageStates[?stageName==`Source`].actionStates[0].currentRevision.revisionId' \
    --output text
```

This assumes the Stage Name is `Source` (can change to whatever you've named your stage), and that the first action in that state is where you retrieve the source code

Comment: Thanks.  When I run the above command, the revisionid I am receiving is not the commitid I am looking for. ( we are using bitbucket, but I don't think that is the issue as other parameters are valid and it does have and return a revision id.

The commit Id - I can see only when I click on "Details", with  a popup

`Review summary
Action name
PromoteToStageApprovalGate
Status
Approved
Comments about this action
Deploy Service to Stage Cluster Approval Required for CommitID=commid
URL for review : urlwcommitid

Reviewer ARN
arn:aws:sts::....
Comments
Approved by  using awscli on`

Comment: And when I run the `aws codepipeline get-pipeline-state \
    --name my-pipeline-name` to get the complete output, there also I do not see the commit id that I see on the pop-up.  Is there some other codepipeline command I need to run to get the commitid?

Comment: That's rough...I imagine it has to do with differences between how codepipeline interacts with github vs bitbucket

Comment: So, currently, I have to go to each pipeline on the console, click on the details and gather the commit id that I then need to attach to my change control ticket.       Anyone else has any other thoughts on how to get this information using aws cli or any other commandline where i can loop through the list of my pipelines and generate a file - pipeline:commitid format?

Comment: Not the most ideal, but assuming you have Codebuild projects as part of your Codepipeline, you have access to the `CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION` [variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html) that will give you the commit id. You could include a command in your codebuiled project to store that value somewhere (DynamoDB, Parameter Store, S3, etc) and query via cli. Lots of work, but could save time long term